# Docker stack deploy ability to pass env variables into the deploy yaml?

Tags: docker

I run a docker swarm and i use gitlab ci to do the build and deployment of the images, the biggest headache i face is incrementing the image version numbers in the deployment yaml.

So for example if i do a deploy on gitlab and build the relevant image like this:

```
docker build --no-cache --platform linux/amd64 -t myregistry/myimage:$CI_COMMIT_TAG -f docker/php-backend/Dockerfile .
```

I am creating the image version number by using the git tag, which works fine. I then transfer the latest deploy.yaml file to the server and make it run:

```
sudo docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c live-deploy.yaml my-stack-name
```

The issue here is, inside my live-deploy.yaml i have to manually update the image name with the new version that was built.

Is there a way (and so far i can't find it) to pass a variable into the yaml from the command line when deploying so it knows what version number to use? A bit like passing in environment variables with docker compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with environment variables to acheive this automation. Example follows:

Sample docker-compose/stack file :-

```
 version: '3.3'
 services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: ${MyImageName}
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

And when you want to deploy something pass `env value` along with the imperative command... your command modifies to :-

```
MyImageName=myregistry/myimage:$CI_COMMIT_TAG docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c live-deploy.yaml my-stack-name
```

You can even keep the image name constant and just have a variable just for the tag if that is the degree of automation required.

Comment: I didn't actually think of doing it that way, i'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, its a simple and scalable automation. Consider templating your docker compose if you have a lot of applications.

Answer (score 0):

For reference see in moby [docker stack deploy in 1.13 doesn't load .env file as docker-compose up does](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133). Specifically [Comment from kinghuang](https://%20https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133#issuecomment-852350362)

"I have my developers use docker-compose config to pre-process Docker Compose projects before passing them to docker stack deploy. You can do this in one line with:

```
docker stack deploy -c <(docker-compose config) stack-name-here
```

That way, all Docker Compose features including .env processing are fully applied."